# Significant overhead for using threads in Ruby for metric collection?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a server that collects and analyzes usage metrics.  I want various pieces of my architecture to periodically send metrics to the server via a REST API.

I don't want to block executing while the metrics are being transmitted, so I've considered spinning off creating a method that will spin off threads:

```
require 'net/http'

module Metrics
  def self.time(time_to_process)
    Thread.new do
      uri = URI.parse(url)
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      # ...do a bunch of setup...
      response = http.request(request)
    end
  end
end
```

...and inside the application.

```
def app_method
  # ...do stuff, measure time
  Metrics.time(time_to_process)
end
```

Since the application code is single threaded, and it takes a second or two for app_method to execute, I don't anticipate having more than 10-100 metric collection threads in action at anyone time so OS thread limits are not a big concern.

However I'm wondering what the overhead in terms of memory and CPU time to spin off the new thread (not counting the memory/CPU required to actually do the Net::HTTP call)?  Is there a significant downside to this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is YES - firing up a new Thread ad-hoc has memory and CPU overhead which are very significant!

The industry standard to avoiding creating a new thread whenever you want to do a background job is using [thread pools](http://burgestrand.se/articles/quick-and-simple-ruby-thread-pool.html), which are simply a number of threads created in advance, waiting to receive messages, and do the work accordingly.

Looking at similar solutions (like [newrelic](http://newrelic.com/)'s), most use a background *process* (or agent) which is in charge of actually sending the information to the server, while the application sends light-weight messages to the agent, which it aggregates and bulk-sends at its convenience.

In a rails system, building a background job from scratch is not recommended, and you should consider using gems like [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/), along with its suggested architecture, to do this for you. Most of those don't depend on Threads within the main application either, but on their own processes (sometimes on their own *machines*), communicating with the application with messages on a queue (using a repository like [Redis](http://redis.io/) for example).

Comment: Bummer, I really hate to add another dependency to the stack like DJ.  I'm going to give it a shot without thread pools since I anticipate having only 3 or 4 threads running at any one time.  We'll see what happens

Comment: BTW, any metrics for exactly what the overhead is in terms of memory?  Googling around I didn't seen any specific numbers

Comment: @juwiley - I don't know the numbers, but if you insist on using ad-hoc threads, you might want to consider Fibers instead - https://www.igvita.com/2009/05/13/fibers-cooperative-scheduling-in-ruby/

Comment: What do you mean by `memory and CPU overhead which are very significant!`? That doesn't really provide much info.

Answer (score 1):

I think your use case for a new thread is actually pretty good. I have created new threads to allow a fast response from the app, and do something in the background.

As Uri mentioned in his answer, the more robust and scalable way to do this is with a background worker, such as Sidekiq. But that requires more overhead and complexity.

One important consideration is failure. What do you want to happen if the background job fails? Logging? Restart? If the answer is restart or some more complex functionality, then a background worker such as Sidekiq would probably be better.

With regard to resources, I don't think that launching a new thread will consume much resources. But it depends on your use case. 1 new thread at a time would not be noticed, but 100 may be way too much. How much CPU and resources will each thread consume?

New Relic is a good way to test this and monitor your app for CPU and memory usage.

Here is some interesting info that should be helpful: [How many threads is too many?](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7970125-how-many-threads-is-too-many)